# AttributeError: 'RegisterPatientView' object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django, templates, django-urls, django-managers

When ever I am running the project and try to create register the patient or doctor it is showing this error. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRRi1.png)
and below it is showing error in [return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KGO8.png)

and if I try  to visit login page it is not rendering.

Below is my code.
**views.py**

```
class RegisterPatientView(CreateView):
    """
        Provides the ability to register as a Patient.
    """
    model = User
    form_class = PatientRegistrationForm
    template_name = 'accounts/patient/register.html'
    success_url = '/'

    extra_context = {
        'title': 'Register'
    }

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        return super().dispatch(self.request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form = self.form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return redirect('accounts:login')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/patient/register.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
from appointment.views import *

app_name = "accounts"

urlpatterns = [
    path('patient/register', RegisterPatientView.as_view(), name='patient-register'),
    path('patient/profile/update/', EditPatientProfileView.as_view(), name='patient-profile-update'),
    path('doctor/register', RegisterDoctorView.as_view(), name='doctor-register'),
    path('doctor/profile/update/', EditDoctorProfileView.as_view(), name='doctor-profile-update'),
    path('login', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from accounts.managers import UserManager

GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('male', 'Male'),
    ('female', 'Female'))


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    role = models.CharField(max_length=12, error_messages={
        'required': "Role must be provided"
    })
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, default="")
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False,
                              error_messages={
                                  'unique': "A user with that email already exists.",
                              })
    phone_number = models.CharField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True, max_length=20,
                                    error_messages={
                                        'unique': "A user with that phone number already exists."
                                    })

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    objects = UserManager()
```

please! help me out and let me know if any other codes required. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you're calling `self.get_success_url()` in `dispatch()`, the `CreateView.get_success_url()` depends the `object` field, that is created on `CreateView.get()` and `CreateView.post()` methods.

I recommend you to change your view to:

```py
class RegisterPatientView(CreateView):
    . . .
    success_url = '/'
    . . .

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
        return super().dispatch(self.request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        form = self.form_class(data=request.POST)
        . . .
```

Comment: I had changed my view to the code you recommend but now it showing other error `'str' object is not callable`.

Comment: Could you show where the error occurred? If it was in the redirect, note that the `self.success_url` should not be called like the `self.get_success_url()`.

Comment: `Internal Server Error: /doctor/register  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\UNIT 4\my_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "F:\UNIT 4\my_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\UNIT 4\my_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) `

Comment: `File "F:\UNIT 4\my_env\drappointment\accounts\views.py", line 56, in dispatch
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
  File "F:\UNIT 4\my_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 122, in get_success_url
    url = self.success_url.format(**self.object.__dict__)
AttributeError: 'RegisterDoctorView' object has no attribute 'object'`  The above is the complete error i had refer this doc everthing is almost same [link]( https://github.com/nazmul199512/django-doctor-appointment/tree/f526a83c887aa0a606369dcd76621cbb485143cc)  ignore the format is jumbled.

Comment: in `/accounts/views.py#L24`, you must use `HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)` not `HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())`

Comment: yeah its working now I am able to create a user and doctor too thank you so much . one question to be asked should I replace all `HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())` to `HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)`  in my all views

Comment: No, only when you use it before the `self.object` is created. If you call the `self.get_success_url()` inside the `get()` and `post()` methods or after the `dispatch()` super call, it should work fine.